# 'this' undefined in child class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I can't use 'this' in the express route. Why is that? Because I need `this.postRepo` in class B's multiple methods. Any alternative way for this?

```ts
// Parent
export default abstract class A {
  // no constructor
  // few methods
}

// Child
export default class B extends A {
  public postRepo: number

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.postRepo = 111;
  }

  public methodA(req?: Request, res?: Response): any {
    console.log(this); // undefined
    console.log(this.postRepo); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'postRepo' of undefined
  }

  // ...methods that required this.postRepo
}

// New
const classB = new B();
classB.methodA(); // <--- this is working
router.get("/", classB.methodA); // <--- undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose methodA is loosing its context. If that is the case, you can replace the method with an arrow function, their context is stable:

```
public methodA = (req?: Request, res?: Response) => {
    console.log(this); // undefined
    console.log(this.postRepo); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'postRepo' of undefined
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

bind the methodA in the constructor.

**this.methodA = this.methodA.bind(this);**

```
// Child
export default class B extends A {
  public postRepo: number

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.postRepo = 111;
    this.methodA = this.methodA.bind(this); // add this line
  }

  public methodA(req?: Request, res?: Response): any {
    console.log(this); // undefined
    console.log(this.postRepo); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'postRepo' of undefined
  }

  // ...methods that required this.postRepo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a guy responded on my Facebook post

`classB.methodA.bind(classB)` is the solution

Answer (score 0):

router.get("/", classB.methodA); Here you are referencing the method, which means it will not carry the context of the instance where you defined the method. either you go with .bind approach or use an arrow function to bind context.

Answer (score 0):

Because the caller is not classB.
this will be default binding which is undefined